# How to use a command SCP on a python Program

Tags: python, ssh, scp

im new to SCP in python , so i dont know how to use a scp command with a python program .
My idea its that with the funnction
`os.system(scp -r .......)`     works , but i have seen that normally its used paramiko , because my scp its to a ssh .
What should i use ? the os.system would work ? or i have to use paramiko , if i uses paramiko , i had to login like a normal ssh ?

Would this work?

```
os.system("scp -r localroute sshroute")
os.system("scp -r localfile sshroute")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "pscp.exe" in windows like below. (I didn't tried it)

```
os.system("<pscp.exe path> -r -pw <ssh_password> localroute sshroute")
```

Comment: and for ubuntu/linux?

Comment: in linux, it's easier. just insert usual scp command inside of os.system()